# Using the pipe key on MageGee MK-BOX (60%)

Tags: keyboard

I have recently bought a MageGee 60% keyboard. The model is MK-BOX. It works as expected for the most part; the issue is when I need to use the pipe symbol. I have tried multiple key combinations to make it appear but have failed. If anyone knows the combination, it is appreciated because I need it for programming, amongst other things. The backslash key, which is the same as the pipe symbol, works. It's only the pipe symbol itself that's the problem. Thanks

I hsve tried the following key combinations: Shift + Backslash, Shift +Alt + Backslash, Fn + Backlash, Fn + Alt + Backslash